# What happens if data intermixes

Tags: protocol-theory

**NOTE**: *The following question can be hypothetical as I don't know whether it really happens or not.I am asking it just out of curiosity*

Suppose I am sending data in a network.The data is in form of `bit stream` like

> 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0

and there is another data which is in the form

> 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0

and somehow both of the data intermixes and the final data is still like

```
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
    ^ ^
```

which is still same as originally transmitted data but the arrowed bits are from 2nd data (due to intermixing)

Now I have two questions in my mind

1)When the receiver receives this data, will it be treated same as that of original data or it will be changed?

2)Does it happen in real life in networking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course data can intermix in the transmission, if the medium is suspectible to that, but there is a ton of protocols and standards with regards to how to protect the data stream from being damaged/modified - at very basic levels, and at more sophisticated levels.

If at bit level the stream is exactly the same even if there was a problem in the transmission path, most of the bit-correction mechanisms won't even notice it. Some more sophisticated mechanisms/protocols will detect transmission/receive problem and try to do some additional evasion - like for example, changing the transmission channel or retransmit just to make sure it's good.

Comment: will the data received by receiver be corrupted or it will remain same?

Comment: The data stream is exactly (at binary level) as it was when sent from sender. If there are no other means to check for transmission validity (like additional, upper-layer information) then yes, the data is at the binary stream level the same. Even with checksum at this level, the data will be validated as correct.